# Append string of text into existing element jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to append some text into this existing text which is on the site, using jQuery. I've tried a lot of parent(), child(), next(), find(), no luck! Please assist. Appreciate it.
Look at the image below.

I've tried this, one of many attempts:

```
$('.align-left').next().append("<p>Usynlig tewfekst test</p>");
```

Here's the HTML, I cut out a lot of the  tags as I don't think they're of any help.

```
<dl class="store-details-info">
  <dt><strong>Adresse:</strong></dt>
  <dd>Solheimveien&nbsp;10,&nbsp;1473&nbsp;Lørenskog</dd>
  <dt><strong>Kundesenter:</strong></dt>
  <dd>21 00 21 21</dd>
  <dt><strong>E-post:</strong></dt>
  <dd><a href="https://www.elkjop.no/kontakt-oss" target="_self">Kontakt oss</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="align-left any-1-1">
  <strong>Om butikken </strong>
  <p>
  </p>
  <div class="oph-module">
    <div style="height: 25px;">
      <div class="element library-elkjop-gui"><i style="color: #141b4d;" class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-header">
      <div>Ukedag</div>
      <div>Dato</div>
      <div>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-content">
      <div class="opening-hours">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <p><strong>Autorisert Apple-reparasjon</strong></p>
  <p>Flere av Elkjøps butikker kan reparere dine Apple-produkter, enten mens du venter eller i løpet av meget kort tid. Les mer om <a href="/cms/autoriserede-reparatoer/autoriseret-apple-reparation/">autorisert Apple-reparasjon hos Elkjøp</a>.</p>
  <p></p>
  <strong>"Klikk &amp; Hent" informasjon: </strong>
  <p>Du finner vår Klikk&amp;hent-utlevering når du går inn hovedinngangen og tar til venstre mot kasse og vareutleveing. Du kan betale med kort i vareutleveringen. Ønsker du å betale med kontanter, henvend deg i kassen først.</p>
  <div id="google-maps-canvas" class="google-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: How is this not a valid question? I provided the last solution I tried which was the closest to working.... What else is missing?

Comment: SO wants to see code. Not pictures of code. It is hard to test a solution if the actual HTML is not provided - it is the missing [mcve] that will mae ppl vote down

Comment: But I don't have access to the code, that's why I want a solution with jQuery and append through there. In this case, only thing I need is the class names, to append it to the correct place, no? If not, I'm sorry. I can copy the code from the console if that's better.

Comment: Yes that IS better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- .next is the next element AFTER the div
- You cannot append a `<p>` in a `<p>`,

To append text to the last paragraph in the selected div, you can do

```js
$('.align-left p:last')
  .html(function() {
    return $(this).text() + '<span class="usynlig">Usynlig tekst test</span>';
  })
```

```css
.usynlig { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="store-details-info">
  <dt><strong>Adresse:</strong></dt>
  <dd>Solheimveien&nbsp;10,&nbsp;1473&nbsp;Lørenskog</dd>
  <dt><strong>Kundesenter:</strong></dt>
  <dd>21 00 21 21</dd>
  <dt><strong>E-post:</strong></dt>
  <dd><a href="https://www.elkjop.no/kontakt-oss" target="_self">Kontakt oss</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="align-left any-1-1">
  <strong>Om butikken </strong>
  <p>
  </p>
  <div class="oph-module">
    <div style="height: 25px;">
      <div class="element library-elkjop-gui"><i style="color: #141b4d;" class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-header">
      <div>Ukedag</div>
      <div>Dato</div>
      <div>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-content">
      <div class="opening-hours">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <p><strong>Autorisert Apple-reparasjon</strong></p>
  <p>Flere av Elkjøps butikker kan reparere dine Apple-produkter, enten mens du venter eller i løpet av meget kort tid. Les mer om <a href="/cms/autoriserede-reparatoer/autoriseret-apple-reparation/">autorisert Apple-reparasjon hos Elkjøp</a>.</p>
  <p></p>
  <strong>"Klikk &amp; Hent" informasjon: </strong>
  <p>Du finner vår Klikk&amp;hent-utlevering når du går inn hovedinngangen og tar til venstre mot kasse og vareutleveing. Du kan betale med kort i vareutleveringen. Ønsker du å betale med kontanter, henvend deg i kassen først.</p>
  <div id="google-maps-canvas" class="google-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

or using the canvas with the ID to navigate to its previous sibling

```js
$("#google-maps-canvas").prev()
  .html(function() {
    return $(this).text() + '<span class="usynlig">Usynlig tekst test</span>';
  })
```

```css
.usynlig { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="store-details-info">
  <dt><strong>Adresse:</strong></dt>
  <dd>Solheimveien&nbsp;10,&nbsp;1473&nbsp;Lørenskog</dd>
  <dt><strong>Kundesenter:</strong></dt>
  <dd>21 00 21 21</dd>
  <dt><strong>E-post:</strong></dt>
  <dd><a href="https://www.elkjop.no/kontakt-oss" target="_self">Kontakt oss</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="align-left any-1-1">
  <strong>Om butikken </strong>
  <p>
  </p>
  <div class="oph-module">
    <div style="height: 25px;">
      <div class="element library-elkjop-gui"><i style="color: #141b4d;" class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-header">
      <div>Ukedag</div>
      <div>Dato</div>
      <div>Åpningstider</div>
    </div>
    <div class="oph-content">
      <div class="opening-hours">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <p><strong>Autorisert Apple-reparasjon</strong></p>
  <p>Flere av Elkjøps butikker kan reparere dine Apple-produkter, enten mens du venter eller i løpet av meget kort tid. Les mer om <a href="/cms/autoriserede-reparatoer/autoriseret-apple-reparation/">autorisert Apple-reparasjon hos Elkjøp</a>.</p>
  <p></p>
  <strong>"Klikk &amp; Hent" informasjon: </strong>
  <p>Du finner vår Klikk&amp;hent-utlevering når du går inn hovedinngangen og tar til venstre mot kasse og vareutleveing. Du kan betale med kort i vareutleveringen. Ønsker du å betale med kontanter, henvend deg i kassen først.</p>
  <div id="google-maps-canvas" class="google-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot test without you posting actual HTML

Comment: That last example appended the whole jquery as well, that's strange. And it appended it too far up.  Watch: 
https://imgur.com/a/ZEYdhOa

Comment: You of course need to wrap the code in `<script></script>` and load jQuery library

Comment: Seems like it is working when I try to inject the script from another CMS tool, but not from our main site builder. Strange! But it works externally so I'm marking this as correct.

Comment: Do you know of any method to make the text which I just added, invisible? Like, set only the css for that additional text to display:none; or something. I tried  ``` var txt = " Usynlig text testest";
   $("#google-maps-canvas").prev()
      .text(function() { return $(this).text() + txt});
      txt.css("display", "none");```  
with no luck

Comment: I appreciate all the help, thanks. I'm quiet new to this. One last bonus question, it isn't possible to make it invisible without using any tags around the new added text, right? The point I want to achieve with this is that the text in that <p> is all pasted into an email, and if I use tags, the tags will be inserted into the email as well. That's why I wanted to append through jquery, but I didn't really think of the tags lol. But thanks!

Comment: No. It is not possible to have invisible text inside a container with visible text without hiding it using some kind of tag.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code helps.

This code `$('.align-left').next().append("<p>Usynlig tewfekst test</p>");`

Can you change it `$('.align-left').append("<p>Usynlig tewfekst test</p>");`

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/wvzwpRQ

Comment: The `p` is not a sibling but a child of the align-left

Comment: This didn't work. It appends, but too far up the structure.